# perl hecking all value once

Tags: perl, hash, arrays

I am basically a networking guy and so not good at writing scripts.

While writing some scripts I came across below requirement.

I have a hash array with some values of "1" or "2" and my requirement

> if all of the value equal to other than "1"  (could be "2" or "3") then it will print some statement once and then come out of that loop.
>
> if any of the value equal to "1" then it will print some statement.

ex:

```
my %hash_array1=(A=>2,B=>2,C=>2);
my @array2=values (%hash_array1);

foreach my $line (@array2) {

    if ($line!=1) {

        print BOLD GREEN "\rNo Evolution ",RESET;

        last;
    }
    else {
        print BOLD RED "Evolution \n",RESET;
    }
}
```

which print

```
No Evolution
```

Above code work well as expected for mentioned hash_array because all values are non-"1",but not working well for below hashes

```
my %hash_array1=(A=>1,B=>2,C=>2);
```

where it prints

```
Evolution

No Evolution
```

which is not as per my expectation. I want here to print as one time "Evolution" and "No Evolution" should not be printed any more. (However loop should be continued to iterate)

Please let me know if more clarity is required.

Regards

Mahesh

Comment: Because I am the networking guy I have to be good at writing scripts ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my %hash_array1=(A=>1,B=>1,C=>2);
my $values = join('', values(%hash_array1));

if ($values =~ /1/) {
    print "at least one 1";
} else {
    print "no 1";
}
```

Comment: This is also a good approach though I suspect the execution time is going to be similar to mine given that `join` has to get all the values and build the string. That being said, you would only need to do the negative match - if it fails, then they're all non "1". The way you have it it only works on a hash containing 3 values, and it's the opposite of his requirement; he wants to know if there's no "1" in the set (or conversely, if there is one - you only need to check for one or the other)

Comment: Thanks. This is great logic with less # of lines of code..great...regards: Mahesh

Answer (score 4):

```
my %hash_array1=(A=>2,B=>2,C=>2);
if ( grep $_ == 1, values %hash_array1 ) {
    print BOLD RED "Evolution \n",RESET;
}
else {
    print BOLD GREEN "\rNo Evolution ",RESET;
}
```

(Some comments are talking about execution time; this shouldn't be a concern unless it is demonstrated that there is a performance issue.)

Comment: Thanks for the valuable logic along with surity of performance issues. Regards--Mahesh

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading your requirement correctly, you're going to need to examine the entire set unless you hit a "1"

Basically, you need to keep a state and exit the loop only if you hit a "1"

```
my %hash_array1=(A=>2,B=>2,C=>2);
my @array2=values (%hash_array1);
my $state = 0;

foreach my $line (@array2) 
{
    if ($line == 1)
    {
        $state = 1;
        last;
    }
}

if ($state == 1)
{
    print BOLD RED "Evolution \n",RESET;
}
else
{
    print BOLD GREEN "\rNo Evolution ",RESET;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, I will try this in my script and will let you know about the results..regards: Mahesh